# Integration - Apache Flink + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-flink

I'm testing the integration between Apache Flink and Spring Boot, to run them on IDE is fine, but when I tried to run on Apache Flink Cluster I had one Exception related to ClassLoader.

The classes are really simple:

**BootFlinkApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class BootFlinkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("some test");
        SpringApplication.run(BootFlinkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**FlinkTest**

```
@Service
public class FlinkTest {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        see.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .filter(new RemoveNumber3Filter()).print();

        try {
            see.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error executing flink job: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**RemoveNumber3Filter**

```
public class RemoveNumber3Filter implements FilterFunction<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Integer i) throws Exception {
        return i != 3;
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:897)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot load user class: com.example.demo.RemoveNumber3Filter
    ClassLoader info: URL ClassLoader:
        file: '/tmp/blobStore-850f3189-807e-4f8d-a8a6-3bd3c1bd76b4/job_eb93b239080b4d4e09f10f1e3605744d/blob_p-5fd56f3348976c0d333d680fde4a79573c21cd40-48ac0995eee11f38ce3ff4f890102af8' (valid JAR)
    Class not resolvable through given classloader.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:355)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:126)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html

Comment: Yes I saw it, but didn't help much...

Comment: Can you check whether `RemoveNumber3Filter` is contained in the jar `blob_p-5fd56f3348976c0d333d680fde4a79573c21cd40-48ac0995eee11f38ce3ff4f890102af8` or in the jar which you use to start the application.

Comment: Yes, it is... The problem is that the jar that spring boot creates has the classes inside the folder BOOT-INF/classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably use the Spring Boot Maven plugin (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) to repackage your Jar to generate an executable jar, however, it uses a custom boot layout which is not supported by Apache Flink's internal class loader. There should be an original jar file next to the one you try to deploy (.jar.original) which you could use for deployment on the Flink cluster.

As an alternative, you can use a different way of generating a Jar with all your dependencies, such as maven-shade (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)