# How to run spring boot jar on apache flink?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-flink

I want to run spring boot application on apache flink as a jar. Can I do it?

Comment: Yes. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/packaging.html

Answer (score 0):

As Randy Mentioned, you need to create Fat Jar which is executable Jar, with that you can run. The below URL helps you,

[Integration - Apache Flink + Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099485/integration-apache-flink-spring-boot)